# Get the right columns when input contains consecutive tabs using read in shell

Tags: shell

My input string is formatted like this:

```
line1: column1    column2    column3
line2: column1               column3
```

So the line2 has a consecutive tab like `column1\t\tcolumn3`and column2 is an empty string.

I want to get the column2 value, but I get column3 in the line2 when I use

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r c1 c2 c3; do  ...echo $c2...; done < input_file `
```

Output is like this:

```
column2
column3
```

I think the shell builtin `read` regards consecutive tabs as just one field separator.

So my question is whether there is a way to avoid this situation using `read`? If not, is there a convenient way to deal with this instead of using `cut -f`?

Comment: consecutive delimiters are ignored by the shell. <s>What's wrong with cut?</s> I see what's wrong. you need to use either awk, python or perl. this is not a job for sh/bash.

Comment: @xvan actually, I want map >4 columns value, If use cut, I have to cut >4 time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct in that a sequence of `IFS` characters can be counted as a single delimiter, namely when they're whitespace, or a non-whitespace character surrounded by whitespace (from the [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting) – emphasis mine):

> #### Word Splitting
>
> [...]
>
> Any character in `IFS` that is not `IFS` whitespace, **along with any
>   adjacent `IFS` whitespace characters, delimits a field. A sequence of
>   `IFS` whitespace characters is also treated as a delimiter.** If the
>   value of `IFS` is null, no word splitting occurs.

One way I can think of to deal with this is preprocessing to insert a space between any two consecutive tab characters.

Without space:

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r c1 c2 c3; do
    printf '1:[%s] 2:[%s] 3:[%s]\n' "$c1" "$c2" "$c3"
done  < input_file
```

Output:

```
1:[column1] 2:[column2] 3:[column3]
1:[column1] 2:[column3] 3:[]
```

Space added with sed:

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r c1 c2 c3; do
    printf '1:[%s] 2:[%s] 3:[%s]\n' "$c1" "$c2" "$c3"
done  < <(sed 's/\t\t/\t \t/g' input_file)
```

Output:

```
1:[column1] 2:[column2] 3:[column3]
1:[column1] 2:[ ] 3:[column3]
```

This works if you're okay with having the space instead of the empty string in `c2` for the second line.

Another option is to use a non-whitespace character in your `IFS`, as those (see manual snippet above) are *not* squeezed when delimiting fields:

```
while IFS='~' read -r c1 c2 c3; do
    printf '1:[%s] 2:[%s] 3:[%s]\n' "$c1" "$c2" "$c3"
done  < <(tr $'\t' '~' < input_file)
```

Output:

```
1:[column1] 2:[column2] 3:[column3]
1:[column1] 2:[] 3:[column3]
```

Now, `c2` in the second line is the empty string, but the downside is that we have to find a character for `IFS` that doesn't appear in our file.

Note that the process substitution (`<(...)`) requires Bash, but the `IFS` related points apply to the POSIX shell as well, see the [specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_05).

Comment: Thought of this, maybe using `\0` as a filling character in sed will preserve better the output aesthetic..

Comment: @xvan I thought of that as well, but it didn't work, not sure why!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk '
{
    if(NF == 4)
        print $3
    else
        print ""
}' text.txt
```

**Output:**

```
column2
#empty line
```

Answer (score 0):

If consecutive delimiters within the white space class is consolidated, the next option is to convert the delimiters to non white space class before using bash read. For example, convert to pipe delimiter instead of a tab:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n'
for txt_record in $(tr "\t" "|" < your_tab_delim_file.txt)
do
  IFS=$'|' read -r field1 field2 field3 <<< "$txt_record"
  echo "[$field1] [$field2] [$field3]"
done
```